# Why do (almost all) NPCs all have average HP?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, npc

In the Monster Manual, all the monsters, even ones with class levels, have average hit points, even for their first hit die. Why do monsters have half the HP that PCs have?

However, the pregenerated NPCs in the DMG have full HP for their first HD, and average HP for the rest of their levels. Where is the distinction made?

Answer (score 7):

According to the page 110 of Dungeon master's guide, creatures built with non elite ability scores array get HP equal to the 1/2 HD on their 1st HD while those built with elite array get full HP.

Creatures in Monster Manual are typically built with average ability scores because they are average creatures of their race/type but pregenerated NPCs in Dungeon Master's guide are built with elite array because they have class levels in **PC** class.